# ler arquivos txt com php

Tags: php, txt

Tenho a seguinte situação: possuo arquivos em formato txt, que são gerados por um outro programa e vou ter que ler linha a linha esse arquivo para gerar boletos de pagamento, nesse arquivo aproximadamente eu terei 40 colunas com dados.
Bem, para efeito de processamento desses dados, seria melhor eu ler esse arquivo txt e ir diretamente fazer a geração dos boletos,ou seria melhor eu colocar esses dados num base de dados e depois para fazer a geração desses boletos eu faria uma leitura desses dados?
Terei arquivos que podem ter mais de 50 linhas de uma só empresa.
Fico preocupado com a performance para fazer tudo isso. Vai gerar os boletos em formato PDF estarei utilizando o HTML2PDF para gerar os pdfs.
Poderia ter uma outra forma de ler esses arquivos txt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta com o file do PHP mesmo.

```
$f = file("arquivo.txt");
foreach($f as $item){
  echo $item .'<br>';
}
```

Comment: Imagino fazer isso,mas me preocupa a performance, imagine que vou ter umas 40 empresas para gerar boletos e cada empresa aproximadamente terá de 30 a 50 boletos.